# Return default value from valueof enum class

Tags: java

I have this enum:

```
public enum View {
    "aaa",
    "bbb",
    "ccc"
}
```

I use valueOf to get constant enum:

```
var v = view.valueOf(someString);
```

In case that someString value is different from  "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" I need
the valueof will return default value "xxx".

My question is how  to return the default value for example "xxx" if input not
equal to one of the strings mentioned above?

Comment: [Can Java enum class set default value](//stackoverflow.com/q/59608461) ... you can't when using `valueOf()`, you would need your own method in that enum to do that.

Comment: FYI: Enum object names are not in quotes. And, as constants, enum object names should be in all uppercase, per Java conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your version of `valueOf()`:

```java
public enum View {
  aaa,bbb,ccc;

  public static View valueOfOrElse(String name) {
    for (View value : values()) {
      if (value.name().equals(name)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return aaa;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enums are constants and should be uppercase by convention.

```
public enum View {
  aaa, bbb, ccc, xxx;

  public static View valueOfOrElse(String name) {
    try {
        return View.valueOf(name);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return xxx;
    }
  }
}
```